# Hot to logic compare a bool array with itself for a single bool result?

Tags: c#, .net, arrays

I have an array that looks like this:

```
bool[] array = new bool[4] { true, false, true, true } ;
```

And I'd like to do an AND/OR comparison between all the elements of this array, something like:

> AND example: true AND false AND true AND true

So I can get the final result which would be false in the example above, or:

> OR example: true OR false OR true OR true

Which would give me true in the example above.

It there any built-in method in an array that allows me to do it? Or should I have to iterate between all elements and compare them one by one?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This can be done with linq:

```
var all = array.All(x => x);
var or = array.Any(x => x);
```

Answer (score 18):

As per comments and other answers, you can use LINQ for both of these. (Although you don't have to; farbiondriven's answer will work absolutely fine, although it's less general purpose in that LINQ solutions can handle *any* `IEnumerable<bool>`.)

[`Any`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_Linq_Enumerable_Any__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0_System_Boolean__) with an identity projection will detect if *any* element is `true`, which is the same result as performing a logical `OR` on all elements.

[`All`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.all?view=netframework-4.7.1) with an identity projection will detect if *all* elements are `true`, which is the same result as performing a logical `AND` on all elements:

```
bool orResult = array.Any(x => x);
bool andResult = array.All(x => x);
```

Both of these will short-circuit: if the first element is `true`, then `Any` won't bother looking at later elements, as the result will definitely be `true`. Likewise if the first element is `false`, then `All` won't bother looking at later elements, as the result will definitely be `false.`

However, you may need to think about what you want the result to be for empty arrays. `Any()` will return `false` on an empty sequence, whereas `All` will return true on an empty sequence. That may or may not be what you expect or need.

Answer (score 2):

Approach with Linq `Aggregate` and binary `&` and `|` operations

```
bool[] array = new bool[4] { true, false, true, true } ;
bool resultAnd = array.Aggregate((a, b) => a & b); // AND
bool resultOr = array.Aggregate((a, b) => a | b); //OR
bool resultXor = array.Aggregate((a, b) => a ^ b); //XOR
```

Comment: Note that this won't short-circuit, whereas `Any` and `All` will.

Comment: Although I've liked Patrick and richej answers more, this one is a good call in case one doesn't want to import a library just to achieve the same goal. Thanks for your response!

Answer (score 1):

If a no LinQ solution may be required :

```
public static bool Or(IList<bool> bList)
{
    return bList.Contains(true);
}

public static bool And(IList<bool> bList)
{
    return !bList.Contains(false);
}
```

Comment: That uses LINQ - it's calling `Enumerable.Contains`. You're right that you don't need LINQ, but this solution happens to use it.

Comment: That now doesn't use LINQ - but won't work for arrays. `IList<T>` will do it though :)

Comment: You're right ! Just in case somebody needs older version of .NET.

Answer (score 1):

> It there any built-in method in an array that allows me to do it?

Answer: Yes.  There are static methods in the [System.Array Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array(v=vs.110).aspx#Methods) that can be used.

For example, [Array.IndexOf Method (T[], T)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eha9t187(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
bool andResult = !(Array.IndexOf<bool>(array, false) > -1);
bool orResult = Array.IndexOf<bool>(array, true) > -1;
```

However, you need to define how you want to handle the edge case of an empty array.

There are other methods in the Array Class that could also be used to construct the logic.  I will leave that exercise for you.